# FORTRAN is faster than C - for a matrix multiplication program running on a same processor, why?

Tags: c, matrix, time, fortran, matrix-multiplication

I was running `n*n` matrix multiplication code using C and FORTRAN on a xeon processor system. I was surprised to see the real time difference between the two approaches. Why did the FORTRAN code gave me a faster execution time? I was using `dgemm()` and called the same function from my C code. I tried to run the general C code changing the loop order and trying with different flags for optimizing the simulation process. I couldn't reach the same response obtained by using `dgemm()`.

FORTRAN code - dgemm():

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "sys/time.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

long long readTSC(void)
{
 /* read the time stamp counter on Intel x86 chips */
  union { long long complete; unsigned int part[2]; } ticks;
  __asm__ ("rdtsc; mov %%eax,%0;mov %%edx,%1"
        : "=mr" (ticks.part[0]),
          "=mr" (ticks.part[1])
        : /* no inputs */
        : "eax", "edx");
 return ticks.complete;
}
volatile double gtod(void)
{
 static struct timeval tv;
 static struct timezone tz;
 gettimeofday(&tv,&tz);
 return tv.tv_sec + 1.e-6*tv.tv_usec;
}

void dgemm (char *transa, char *transb, int *x, int *xa, int *xb, double    *alphaa, double *ma, int *xc, double *mb, int *xd, double *betaa, double *msum,   int *xe);
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
   int n = atoi(argv[1]);
   long long tm;

  //disabling transpose, disabling addition operation in C :=       alpha*op(A)*op(B) + beta*C
 char trans='N';
 double alpha=1.0;
 double beta=0.0;


 long long int p=2*n*n*n;
 long double q;
 double *a,*b,*sum;
 double t_real,t,flop_clk,flops;
 int i,j,k;

 //memory allocation
 a=(double*)malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));
 b=(double*)malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));
 sum=(double*)malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));

 //Matrix Initialization
 for (i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
       a[i+n*j]=(double)rand();
      b[i+n*j]=(double)rand();
      sum[i+n*j]=0.0;
    }
 }

//Clock cycles computation using timing2 function and t_real using timing1   function
  t = gtod();

 tm = readTSC();
//dgemm function call
 dgemm(&trans, &trans, &n, &n, &n, &alpha, a, &n, b, &n, &beta, sum, &n);
 tm = readTSC() - tm;
 t_real = gtod() - t;
 return 0;
 }
```

C Code
simply take sum=0 and then

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  for (k=0;k<n;k++)
  {
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
      sum [i+n*j] +=a[i+n*k]*b[k+n*j];
    }
  }
}
```

Compilation:

- icc –o executable program.c for the C code
- icc ­-o executable program.c ­mkl=sequential for the Fortran one

Performance

With matrix order of 5000*5000, I got 4.2 GFLOPS in my code and 21.7 GFLOPS using dgemm().

Comment: There could be many reasons, but generally Fortran have been designed for mathematical work and the Fortran compilers (which started out good) have only become better in the last almost 60 years of the language existance.

Comment: There will be plenty of speculation with a question like this, but no one will be able to give you an accurate answer unless you show both the Fortran and C code with your question.  Explaining how you measured your benchmarks is a good idea too. Details about what tools, compilers, and compiler flags passed would be useful too.

Comment: Please **show some code** so edit your question.

Comment: If OP chooses to revise this question in hope of having it re-opened, I suggest OP provides figures to show what the time difference was between the programs.

Comment: Besides the answers given in the duplicate, the column-major vs row-major nature sometimes affects cache performance.

Comment: @o11c It does, but not Fortran vs. C, but just if you access the array right in both of them.

Answer (score 5):

You still do not show enough for a definitive answer. Notably, in any question about performance when you say that something is faster, you should show the actual measurements you did and the commands you used to compiled the executables.

Anyway, some conclusions can be made.

1. You appear not to use any optimization (the `-O` or `-fast` flags). Any performance analysis is essentially pointless then.
2. From the source code you showed it is cleare that you do not compare the same thing at all, you are comparing two different algorithms. There is absolutely no point comparing the speed of two different algorithms. `gemm` does not contain such simple loops you use in your own code, it is much more complicated mainly for optimal cache utilization.
3. You use the very naive way of multiplying the matrices in your own C code. The fact that you are now (according to one of your comments) now faster than `gemm` is actually very worrying. Are you sure you used large enough matrices? There is no point calling `gemm` on matrices 10x10, they should have some substantial size. `gemm` should be much faster than the naive loops for sufficiently sized matrices. The original figures of 4.2 and 22 GFLOPS sound reasonable if you do not use any compiler optimization for your own function.
4. You claim you are comparing with Fortran. This is NOT true. Only the reference BLAS implementation is written in Fortran but it is not used for serious computation where fast BLAS actually is needed. MKL, which you appear to be using, is not written in Fortran, it is a very optimized assembly code. There are other implementations of BLAS available (ATLAS, GotoBLAS, OpenBLAS) and they are normally not written in Fortran, but in C or assembly.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. Yes, both are two different algorithms, but computes the same operation. I tried with n=1000, 2000, and 5000. With order 5000, I got 4.2 GFLOPS in my code and 21.7 GFLOPS using dgemm().

Comment: The `gemm` from BLAS does the operation in a much clever way, it is a different algorithm and should be faster for large enough matrices. You said in other comment that with `restrict` it is reverse, what does that mean? Did you try compiler optimizations at all? (you should) The timing info belongs to the question, not here.

Answer (score 4):

Just a guess, since the OP is not showing any code. If he is calling [dgemm](http://www.math.utah.edu/software/lapack/lapack-blas/dgemm.html) (from LAPACK BLAS), it is probably written in Fortran.

[Pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing) rules are different in C and in Fortran.

You might use (with care!) the `restrict` keyword when declaring formals in your C routines. This should help.

Also, arithmetic is different in C and in Fortran. In *some* dialects of C (e.g. C89), every floating point operation is computed on double-precision numbers. IIRC it is defined differently in Fortran. And it has changed between C89 & C99 (and perhaps also in C11).

If your two codes are compiled by a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (i.e. using `gcc -O2 foo.c` for C code, and `gfortran -O2 foo.f90` for Fortran90 code) the two compilers produces both similar internal representation (Gimple, you might get it with `-fdump-tree-ssa` or many other `-fdump` flags which produce hundreds of dump files...) and then are optimizing it. So in that case the compiler backends are the same, the middle end is quite similar, but the front ends are really different.

You could simply look at the assembly code (using `gcc -O2 -fverbose-asm` & `gfortran -O2 -fverbose-asm`) and spot the differences.

You might use additional options like `-ffast-math` (which enables the compiler to optimize even against the standard) or `-mtune=native` (which asks the GCC compiler to optimize for your particular processor) in addition of `-O2` or `-O3` optimization flags...

Comment: No, it is speculative. We don't know what code the OP is compiling.

Comment: Thanks a lot Basile. It worked. I simple used the restrict pointer and now the result is just reverse. Thanks. Could you please throw more light on this? I couldn't get though why you gave a down vote? I was pretty serious  about this question. I thought dgemm() was pretty well known.

Comment: We cannot help if you don't show your code. Your code, and how you compile it, matters a lot if speaking of performance.

Comment: Not showing any code nor any compilation commands is why your question got downvoted with good reasons

Comment: Well, now I have updated the codes. Please check it.

Comment: I have also included in my original post, the compilation command I used.